# Aplicativo mobile com erro

Tags: apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo utilizando Apache Cordova + JQuery mobile. Em determinado ponto estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
var nome = $("#txtNome").val();
var sobrenome = $("#txtSobrenome").val();
var sexo = $("#selectSexo").val();
var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
var login = $("#txtLogin").val();
var senha = $("#txtSenha").val(); 
$.ajax({  
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
},
url: mainURL + usuarioURL + '/inserir',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(resp){
  $.mobile.loading('hide');
  alert(resp.status);
},
error: function(e){
  alert('Error occured: ' + e);
},
beforeSend: function(){
  $.mobile.loading('show');
},

data: JSON.stringify({
  nome: nome,
  sobrenome: sobrenome,
  sexo: sexo,
  email: email,
  login: login,
  senha: senha
})
});
```

No browser isso funciona perfeitamente, porém quando faço o mesmo no celular, ocorre um erro e a seguinte mensagem aparece: **Error Ocurred: [object Object]**

Alguém sabe o motivo? Obrigado. Os logs estão apresentados a seguir:

```
    /www/gu.js: Line 55 : readyState: 0
    getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
    var match;
    if ( state === 2 ) {
    if ( !responseHeaders ) {
    responseHeaders = {};
    while ( (match = rheaders.exec( responseHeadersString )) ) {
    responseHeaders[ match[1].toLowerCase() ] = match[ 2 ];
    }
    }
    match = responseHeaders[ key.toLowerCase() ];
    }
    return match == null ? null : match;
    }
    getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
    return state === 2 ? responseHeadersString : null;
    }
    setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
    var lname = name.toLowerCase();
    if ( !state ) {
    name = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] || name;
    requestHeaders[ name ] = value;
    }
    return this;
    }
    overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
    if ( !state ) {
    s.mimeType = type;
    }
    return this;
    }
    statusCode: function ( map ) {
    var code;
    if ( map ) {
    if ( state < 2 ) {
    for ( code in map ) {
    // Lazy-add the new callback in a way that preserves old ones
    statusCode[ code ] = [ statusCode[ code ], map[ code ] ];
    }
    } else {
    // Execute the appropriate callbacks
    jqXHR.always( map[ jqXHR.status ] );
    }
    }
    return this;
    }
    abort: function ( statusText ) {
    var finalText = statusText || strAbort;
    if ( transport ) {
    transport.abort( finalText );
    }
    done( 0, finalText );
    return this;
    }
    state: function () {
    return state;
    }
    always: function () {
    deferred.done( arguments ).fail( arguments );
    return this;
    }
    then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
    var fns = arguments;
    return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
    jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
    var fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
    // deferred[ done | fail | progress ] for forwarding actions to newDefer
    deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
    var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
    if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
    returned.promise()
    .done( newDefer.resolve )
    .fail( newDefer.reject )
    .progress( newDefer.notify );
    } else {
    newDefer[ tuple[ 0 ] + "With" ]( this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this, fn ? [ returned ] : arguments );
    }
    });
    });
    fns = null;
    }).promise();
    }
    promise: function ( obj ) {
    return obj != null ? jQuery.extend( obj, promise ) : promise;
    }
    pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
    var fns = arguments;
    return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
    jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
    var fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
    // deferred[ done | fail | progress ] for forwarding actions to newDefer
    deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
    var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
    if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
    returned.promise()
    .done( newDefer.resolve )
    .fail( newDefer.reject )
    .progress( newDefer.notify );
    } else {
    newDefer[ tuple[ 0 ] + "With" ]( this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this, fn ? [ returned ] : arguments );
    }
    });
    });
    fns = null;
    }).promise();
    }
    done: function () {
    if ( list ) {
    // First, we save the current length
    var start = list.length;
    (function add( args ) {
    jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
    var type = jQuery.type( arg );
    if ( type === "function" ) {
    if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
    list.push( arg );
    }
    } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
    // Inspect recursively
    add( arg );
    }
    });
    })( arguments );
    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
    // current firing batch?
    if ( firing ) {
    firingLength =
04-28 19:24:58.367  21790-21790/com.greeningu I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(55)] "readyState: 0
    getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
    var match;
    if ( state === 2 ) {
    if ( !responseHeaders ) {
    responseHeaders = {};
    while ( (match = rheaders.exec( responseHeadersString )) ) {
    responseHeaders[ match[1].toLowerCase() ] = match[ 2 ];
    }
    }
    match = responseHeaders[ key.toLowerCase() ];
    }
    return match == null ? null : match;
    }
    getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
    return state === 2 ? responseHeadersString : null;
    }
    setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
    var lname = name.toLowerCase();
    if ( !state ) {
    name = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] || name;
    requestHeaders[ name ] = value;
    }
    return this;
    }
    overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
    if ( !state ) {
    s.mimeType = type;
    }
    return this;
    }
    statusCode: function ( map ) {
    var code;
    if ( map ) {
    if ( state < 2 ) {
    for ( code in map ) {
    // Lazy-add the new callback in a way that preserves old ones
    statusCode[ code ] = [ statusCode[ code ], map[ code ] ];
    }
    } else {
    // Execute the appropriate callbacks
    jqXHR.always( map[ jqXHR.status ] );
    }
    }
    return this;
    }
    abort: function ( statusText ) {
    var finalText = statusText || strAbort;
    if ( transport ) {
    transport.abort( finalText );
    }
    done( 0, finalText );
    return this;
    }
    state: function () {
    return state;
    }
    always: function () {
    deferred.done( arguments ).fail( arguments );
    return this;
    }
    then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
    var fns = arguments;
    return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
    jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
    var fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
    // deferred[ done | fail | progress ] for forwarding actions to newDefer
    deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
    var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
    if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
    returned.promise()
    .done( newDefer.resolve )
    .fail( newDefer.reject )
    .progress( newDefer.notify );
    } else {
    newDefer[ tuple[ 0 ] + "With" ]( this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this, fn ? [ returned ] : arguments );
    }
    });
    });
    fns = null;
    }).promise();
    }
    promise: function ( obj ) {
    return obj != null ? jQuery.extend( obj, promise ) : promise;
    }
    pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
    var fns = arguments;
    return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
    jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
    var fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
    // deferred[ done | fail | progress ] for forwarding actions to newDefer
    deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
    var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
    if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
    returned.promise()
    .done( newDefer.resolve )
    .fail( newDefer.reject )
    .progress( newDefer.notify );
    } else {
    newDefer[ tuple[ 0 ] + "With" ]( this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this, fn ? [ returned ] : arguments );
    }
    });
    });
    fns = null;
    }).promise();
    }
    done: function () {
    if ( list ) {
    // First, we save the current length
    var start = list.length;
    (function add( args ) {
    jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
    var type = jQuery.type( arg );
    if ( type === "function" ) {
    if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
    list.push( arg );
    }
    } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
    // Inspect recursively
    add( arg );
    }
    });
    })( arguments );
    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
    // current firing batch?
    if ( firing ) {
    firingLength = list.length;
    // With
```

Comment: O log imprimiu o arquivo JavaScript inteiro!

Comment: Sim. Sabe se existe alguma restrição do phonegap quando estou usando smartphones? Alguma configuração a mais? A mesma requisição funciona no pc pelo navegador.

Comment: Todos os meus apps em phonegap funcionam perfeitamente neste sentido sem nenhum restrição.

Comment: Ah, tenho uma suspeita. No seu XML de configuração, na opção de habilitar origens, set pata *. Ou seja, todas as origens isso deve funcionar

Comment: seria este: <access origin="*" />

Comment: Exatamente. Autoriza para todas as origens.

Comment: não funcionou cara.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisa

Comment: Obrigado vou fazer isso também aqui também.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui, em data, não precisa converter o json em string.

```
data: { nome: nome, sobrenome: sobrenome, sexo: sexo, email: email, login: login, senha: senha }
```

No mais, não vejo erro

Comment: Então se eu não converter, quando a mensagem chega no servidor, ocorre um erro, pois a mesma fica assim por exemplo: nome=fffff&sobrenome=ffffff&sexo=M&email=fffffff&login=fffffffff&senha=fffffff e o WebService está esperando um objeto JSON

Comment: Ahhh entendi. O próprio webservice aguarda um json como post. entendi. A indicação que fiz foi para passar como POST normal.
Faça o seguinte, debugar usando alertas é complicado, pois um  alerta não exibe o conteúdo de um objeto, por isso aparece [object Object]. Use o console.log(e); mas para ver o erro você deve estra com o smartphone que está usando de teste conectado ao PC e com o soft ADB (no caso do andoid) rodando para você verificar o erro que aparece.

Comment: Se não tiver como usar um software tipo ADB, faça essa modificação em sua função error: 
function(e){ var _txt = ''; $.each(e, function(_k,_v){ _txt += _k+': '+_v+'\n'; }); alert(_txt); }
isso vai exibir um alerta mais detalhado. Nos diga que erro aparece.

Comment: Então, usei console.log(e) e foi apresentadomo seguinte: 04-27 23:28:05.857  22593-22593/com.greeningu D/CordovaLog﹕ file:///android_asset/www/gu.js: Line 55 : [object Object]
04-27 23:28:05.857  22593-22593/com.greeningu I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(55)] "[object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/gu.js (55)

Comment: Exibi o conteúdo da variável que _txt no console. apareceu um código bem grande, acho que não cabe nos comentários.

Comment: Edita a pergunta e adicione esse texto

Comment: Pronto Walter, o log foi adicionado